# How does google return "searches" from other websites?

Tags: search

Let's say I'm performing a google search for `search term`.

Sometimes, one of the suggestions will be to a URL like this: `www.someothersearch.com/search+term/`

How does "someothersearch.com" do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a page will only be in Google if some other page links to it.  Google is not going to go to someothersearch.com and submit "search term" into the form, it is likely a hidden or nonhidden link on someothesearch.com.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? someothersearch.com presumably has its own index pages for terms searched previously; the Google spider is just indexing those index pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Maybe these sites support [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1)?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question at first; What these sites are doing is rewriting their requests.  How they know which terms people will search for is a bit of a mystery to me, but it probably relies on things like watching [google.com/trends](http://google.com/trends), scraping their own and other log files for referral from google that include the search term, buying lists of well ranking terms people might use AdSense for and instead trying to generate natural traffic for them... etc. Probably when they add new pages with these terms they're also adding them to their [xml sitemap](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/docs/en/protocol.html) that Google will crawl.

Redacted:
I have added the [Open-Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-search) tag to your question; please follow it. You'll find this post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830/firefox-and-ie7-users-here-is-your-stackoverflow-search-plugin[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830/firefox-and-ie7-users-here-is-your-stackoverflow-search-plugin)the most informative; however I recommend you use image/png for your icon format.